# Loading a page Click the Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi friends I am trying many ways to onloading the page click the anchor tag using jquery or JavaScript.

must see the rel attribute .

```
<div id="local">
    <a id="fmp-button" href="#" rel="http://google.com">
        click
    </a>
</div>
<script>
//$('#fmp-button').trigger('click');

//$("a[href='#']").click();

//$('#fmp-button').click();

//$('#fmp-button')[0].click();

//$(function(){
//    window.location.href = $('#fmp-button').attr('href');
//});

</script>
```

I am tried all the ways
Any one help me how to click the anchor tag when time of page loading anchor tag must be rel attribute

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just change the page, then this will do:

```
window.location = $('#fmp-button').attr('rel');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```
<div id="local">
                <a id="fmp-button" href="http://google.com">
                    click
                </a>
            </div>
<script>

$(function(){
 $('#fmp-button').click();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's another way...

```
<div id="local">
    <a id="fmp-button" href="#" rel="http://google.com">click</a>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#fmp-button' ,function() {
        var url = $('#fmp-button').attr('rel');
        window.location.replace(url);
    });
</script>
```